# Angular - Creating an object map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, dictionary

I need to be able to dynamically create parameter objects in Angular which have the following form:

```
[
    password: {type: 'String', required: true, value: 'apassword'},
    someRandomParam: {type: 'Integer', required: false, value:3}
]
```

I know how to bind to this in order to display the values in a list or table, but I don't know how to construct this object with bindings in Angular, primarily in creating the key ("password") as these keys are created dynamically too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant having an object, not an array (your code will generate SyntaxError), like that:

```
$scope.params = {
    password: {type: 'String', required: true, value: 'apassword'},
    someRandomParam: {type: 'Integer', required: false, value:3}
};
```

It's true that you can bind to it, even using ngRepeat. But adding something to that object needs something more than just a simple bind. Create some inputs in your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newParamName" />
<input type="text" ng-model="newParam.type" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="newParam.required" />
<input type="text" ng-model="newParam.value" />
<input type="button" ng-click="addParam(newParamName, newParam)" value="Add me!" />
```

...and in controller:

```
$scope.addParam = function(name,param){
    $scope.params[name] = angular.copy(param);
};
```

Comment: How would I then delete it from the hashmap if necessary?

Comment: Follow the same pattern - create input to type the name of the param, button, and function `delParam(name)` with `delete $scope.params[name];` in it.